# Matrix as a list of the matrix row prolog

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

I have to representing a matrix as a list of the matrix rows with the term 
like this `[[a,b],[c,d]]` with representing numbers in Peano notation.

I have to obtain a row of matrix

`ow(X,N,C)`: C is the N-th row of matrix X. and the column of matrix

`column(X,N,C)`: C es the N-th column of matrix X.

alse this One to decompose a matrix in its first column and the rest of the matrix
   (which is exactly the same matrix but without the first column):

```
first_column(X,C,R): matrix X is formed by a first column C in
                     front of matrix R.
```

Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peano' notation simplifies expressing recursive algorithms.
I assume matrix indexing is 0 based, and will show you how to get the simplest task of your assignment.

```
row([Row|_], 0, Row).
row([_|Rows], succ(N), Row) :- row(Rows, N, Row).
```

test (get the *second* row, with index 1):

```
?- row([[a,b], [c,d]], succ(0), R).
R = [c, d] ;
false.
```

This shows the essential ingredients you'll use to answer the other two tasks.

Comment: `s/1` is much more common that `succ/1`.

Comment: @false: You're right. I've been exposed to succ/1 by a Pereira Schreiber textbook translatated to Italian. I thought succ/1 could be a bit more descriptive.